# JQuery alternative for YUI ajaxFuntion()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, yui

i have an YUI Ajax function to post/get data and it looks like that:

```
ajaxFunction(url,whichDiv,formID,fnAfterLoading)
```

In this case formID value is a dataString that automatically collects input fields and post it to PHP.

My question is to know whats the alternative for jQuery ajax function passing form values as dataString. Do i always have to prespecify it like so: var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&email=' + email + '&phone=' + phone; or is there an automated collection method?

Thank You

Comment: Good formatting is your friend.

Comment: Also try http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer. 
Basically idea is to use .serialize() to harvest the input data from within the form.

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery.ajax` is the low level AJAX method call of the jQuery API.

Depending on your needs, you may use the shorthand methods such as `get` or `post` show at http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

What are you trying to achieve?